# Use .NET BigInteger as bit field

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory, biginteger

I would like to use `System.Numeric.BigInteger` as bit field.
I have flags in range 1 - 2^255.
Is there any performance reason (memory or speed) to write custom container or I can just use `BigInteger` for this?

Comment: `BigInteger` is immutable, so any change needs to allocate a new one. But unless you're using this in a tight loop or with large values (much larger than 256 bits), it shouldn't matter.

Comment: There is the `BitArray` class, designed for this. Using `List<byte>` is pretty easy as well. If you're willing to sacrifice memory, `List<bool>` is another alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is *tailored* for that kind of storage, and after 
if you need *to store*, you can store it like a sequence of chars, or use some other serialization option.

Comment: That class is a bit weird. For some reason it doesn't implement `IList`, and it wasn't modified to add generic interfaces either. I'd expect it to implement `IList<bool>`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: probably the idea of it is to process _stream_ of bit values. in CLR when ms wants to manifest such usecase of a type, usually stops on implementing it from IEnumerable, or at maximum, from ICollection.